# Run a AsyncTask every 10 seconds until cancelled

Tags: android, android-asynctask, handler

In my application, I have a button that starts an AsyncTask that downloads data with coordinates for google maps, then draws a marker on the map at the following coordinates. I want to run this every 10 seconds until the user presses the button again.

Here's my code for the handler:

```
    class handleMap{
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    Runnable mTask = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(btnRefreshPressed == false){

                try{
                    new getGoogleMap().execute();
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mTask, INTERVAL);
                    Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
                } catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public void starReapetingClass (){
        hMap.starReapetingClass();
    }
    public void stopDoing(){
        mHandler.stopDoing();
    }
}
```

And in the menubutton where it is called:

```
    case R.id.id_Refresh:
        handleMap hMap = new handleMap();
        if(btnRefreshPressed == true){
            menuItem = item;
            menuItem.setActionView(R.layout.progressbar);
            menuItem.expandActionView();


            fRun += 1;
            btnRefreshPressed = false;
            hMap.run();
        }else if(btnRefreshPressed == false){
            if(fRun > 0){
                menuItem.collapseActionView();
                menuItem.setActionView(null);
            }
            btnRefreshPressed = true;
            hMap.stopHandler();
        }
```

This currently causes the application to freeze, and the system outputs a dialog saying that the app isn't responding, and asking if I want to close or wait.

I suspect it has to with the while statement, but I don't get any errors in logcat.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
private int mSampleDurationTime = 10000;
private boolean continueToRun = true;

mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, mSampleDurationTime);
```

where `mRunnable` is your task:

```
private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

 //...
public void run() {

   ...

   if(continueToRun == true){
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, mSampleDurationTime);
   }

 }
    ...
};
```

First time you call `postDelayed` and invoke `new Runnable()`. After, if you want to continue,
call the same method into `run()`

Comment: Lets say you have button that runs all the stuff, so put it into `onButtonClick()`

Comment: I updated my question with how I tried to implement your answer, and It works, I can see how i get the data, but the application still freezes.

Comment: You have UI thread (main) and logic Thread. If you want to update GUI to prevent freeze, use handler.